# Strange use of the & operator in a return expression

Tags: c++, c, function, return

I don't understand the functionality of "&" in the first example 
I have not experiences this kind of return statements in c before , kindly explain ! 
Thanks

Here is the example of some functions

```
uint hashToRange(int h)        {return h & mask;}
 // In this example mask is the data member of generic class 
 // These are some similar examples
   bool lessIndex(intT a, intT b) 
   {
        return 2 * hashToRange(a - b) > m;
   }

   inline int hashInt(unsigned int a) {  

      return hash(a) & (((unsigned) 1 << 31) - 1);
    }
```

Comment: [List of C++ operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators)

Comment: @Borgleader I know the operators but how are they working in the return statement! That explanation is required

Comment: I do not understand all the downvoting going on here. The expression is not trivial unless you've seen it before.

Comment: @SaadHussain You can use any kind of expression statement for a `return` value, as long the resulting type is correct. So use of any operator is possible.

Comment: `(((unsigned) 1 << 31) - 1)` is the same as `0x7fffffff`, if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator `&` is a bitwise AND operator. In this particular case it is used to mask out the sign bit in a 32-bit number.

Here is how it works: the value of `(unsigned) 1 << 31` in binary is a number with bit 31 set to 1, and all remaining bits set to zero:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Subtracting `1` from it produces a number with the lower 31 bits set to `1`, and the sign bit set to zero<sup>*</sup>:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

This becomes the mask applied to `hash(a)`. When you perform a bitwise AND on it, you end up with a number that has all bits of `hash(a)` except the most significant "sign" bit, which is now set to zero.

**Note:** this code makes an assumption that `int` and `unsigned` are both 32-bit types. The standard does not guarantee that this is going to be true. A better approach would be to use `int32_t` and `uint32_t` types to ensure the exact size.

<sup>*</sup> The same principle is at work here as in a situation when you subtract 1 from 10000 and get 9999 back.

Comment: It is being assumed that `sizeof unsigned` is 4.